# Pyspark ALS Recommendation Error: " requirement failed: No ratings available "

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, recommendation-engine

I am running ALS model(Alternating Least Squares matrix factorization method)  for a recommendation engine and getting this error which I am not able to resolve even after spending hours. The data types and format for model arguments are correct according to the model function definition

Please help

```
###Modeling codes
train_df = train_df.dropDuplicates() 

als_model = ALS( implicitPrefs=True,coldStartStrategy="drop",userCol="userID_index", itemCol="itemID_index", ratingCol="rating")
als_model.setSeed(345)
grid = (ParamGridBuilder()
        .addGrid(als_model.rank,[8,10])
        .addGrid(als_model.regParam,[0.1,0.5])
        .addGrid(als_model.alpha, [40])
        .build()
        )
als_eval = RegressionEvaluator(metricName='rmse', labelCol='rating')

cv = CrossValidator(estimator=als_model, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=als_eval,numFolds=1)
train_df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
cv_model = cv.fit(train_df)
```

Error is here

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4662.fit.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No ratings available from MapPartitionsRDD[3167] at map at ALS.scala:613
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.fit(ALS.scala:622)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-202a4259227e> in <module>
     16 cv = CrossValidator(estimator=als_model, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=als_eval,numFolds=1)
     17 train_df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
---> 18 cv_model = cv.fit(train_df)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    230             validation = df.filter(condition)
    231             train = df.filter(~condition)
--> 232             models = est.fit(train, epm)
    233             for j in range(numModels):
    234                 model = models[j]

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     57             params = dict()
     58         if isinstance(params, (list, tuple)):
---> 59             return [self.fit(dataset, paramMap) for paramMap in params]
     60         elif isinstance(params, dict):
     61             if params:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     57             params = dict()
     58         if isinstance(params, (list, tuple)):
---> 59             return [self.fit(dataset, paramMap) for paramMap in params]
     60         elif isinstance(params, dict):
     61             if params:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     60         elif isinstance(params, dict):
     61             if params:
---> 62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
     64                 return self._fit(dataset)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    266         return self._create_model(java_model)
    267 

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    260         """
    261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: No ratings available from MapPartitionsRDD[3167] at map at ALS.scala:613'
```

However I couldn't find any issue with my dataset 'train_df' or the syntax of the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image: train_df]

Comment: exception points to an internal error which happens when converting Java gateway into a Python object. (see https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/master/py4j-python/src/py4j/protocol.py) this usually occurs with incompatible types. Can you round  the train dataset rating column to map 2-3 decimal precision and try again without modifiying the code. If there are other columns similar to rating column have large decimal precision, round those up as well.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: It was negative values causing issue. Code worked after treating for it

Comment: For my case, it was the value of the numFolds (which was 1) in CrossValidator.